# How to insert code php on javascript in smarty template

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I have a sample code:
in .php

```
STemplate::assign('image', 'test.png');
```

in .tpl

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
var image_src = {$image};
alert(image_src);
</script>
{/literal}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You probably want it to be `"{$image}";` so that the javascript parser will see `test.png` as a string and not some javascript statement

Answer (score 3):

Your `{` are not working as smarty code, because you are in a `literal` block. You can break out of it like so:

```
{literal}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var image_src = '{/literal}{$image}{literal}';
        alert(image_src);
    </script>
{/literal}
```

or, as you are not using `{` in javascript, do this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var image_src = '{$image}';
        alert(image_src);
    </script>
```

I've also added some `'` I think you need.

Comment: (If you do need `{` in the javascript, you can use `{ldelim}` when not using `{literal}` by the way)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem below 3 ways

1.

```
{literal}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunc(){
            var image_src = {/literal}{$image}{literal};
            alert(image_src);
        }
    </script>
{/literal}
```

2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunc(){ldelim}
            var image_src = {$image};
            alert(image_src);
        {rdelim}
</script>
```

3.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myImage = {$image}
  {literal}
        function myFunc(){
            var image_src = myImage;
            alert(image_src);
        }
  {literal}
</script>
```